# Access report printout (or PDF) is missing information visible on print preview

Tags: ms-access, printing, vba, report

I added VBA to my report to include blank rows in the invoice, got this code from [here](http://vb123.com.au/200310_dl_pad.htm). The print preview is showing me the blank rows I want, but when I want to export it to PDF or print the report, it shows me invisible text (instead of only in the blank rows). I edited the original code to reset the incremental numbering, but this only works when switching from report view to print preview (the problem was originaly here also, I figured when printing or exporting it would also requery the report and hence the problem would be solved, but to no avail).

This is the code that gives me the blank rows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Const iLines As Integer = 15
Private iTotal As Integer

      ' code added to make count able to reset on report load
      Private iLine As Integer

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  ' get total record count
  iTotal = DCount("*", "OrderLine", "fkOrderID = " & TempVars!tempOrderID)

        ' code added to reset count
        iLine = 0

End Sub
Private Sub Details_Format(Cancel As Integer, _
                           FormatCount As Integer)

        ' code added to reset visibility
        Me!Item.Visible = True
        Me!qty.Visible = True
        Me!CalcPrijs.Visible = True
        Me!TotPrijs.Visible = True

  ' increment iLine on each detail format
  iLine = iLine + 1
  If iLine < iTotal Then
    ' do nothing ... print as usual
  ElseIf iLine = iTotal Then
    ' if there are more lines to print, set the
    ' NextRecord property to false, preventing
    ' the report from exiting prematurely
    If iLine < iLines Then Me.NextRecord = False
  Else
    ' changed this to make text invisible instead of white
    Me!Item.Visible = False
    Me!qty.Visible = False
    Me!CalcPrijs.Visible = False
    Me!TotPrijs.Visible = False
    ' prevent report from advancing past last row
    ' until all of blank lines has have printed
    If iLine < iLines Then Me.NextRecord = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Am I missing something here? I was hoping a good looking print preview would give me a good looking printout. Is there a way I can get the extra blank rows without losing my data on the printout? I added a few pictures to clarify what I want.

Print Preview
[image: Print Preview]

PDF output
[image: PDF output]

Comment: I also tried the approach [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/93448-Adding-extra-lines-at-end-of-Access-report-(Access-2003)), but I get the same problem.

Comment: Hey there, can you put a debug.print "I'm going here" at the top of the `Details_Format` sub and try the print action again? It seems like this sub isn't being called when a print action is called, only when the Open event fires. You may need to call the `Details_Format` sub manually in the Sub where you are printing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The changes I made to reset iLine in the report_open don't fire when I try to save it as PDF. Is there a sub I can call to determine a new generation of the report on printing or exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Had to call the `pageHeaderSection_Print` sub
 to reset the iLine variable when the report is formatted for printing, now everything is working as I wanted.